Please suggest a stotra that can be helpful in controlling excessive lust from our minds
I would like to know if there is a stotra which removes lustful thoughts and longing. Thanks 

Hearing the vani (pure sound vibrations) of great souls who're totally free from lust for many hours daily can help control lust. It's certainly more powerful than chanting a stotra oneself.

The simple answer to this is that you can chant stotra of any God you believe in. You need to understand that our mind is materialistic and it runs towards lust, greed, anger, attachment and ego. The main thing you need to do is control your mind from wandering towards materialistic things.
Bhagavad Geeta talks about controlling the mind in Chapter 6 (https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/6). Particularly, Chapter 6 Verse 35 talks about it.
There are two ways to control your mind: abhyas (Practice) and Vairagya (Detachment)
Practice - Every time your mind thinks of lust, you should bring it back and focus on God. Whenever you sit and chant stotra or meditate you should focus on your Isht Dev. Your mind will wander but every time that happens you should try bringing your focus back on God.
Detachment - Practicing to keep your mind away from things your mind is attached to. When you become master of detachment you will also detach yourself from the pain and pleasure in this temporary materialistic world.
